# IBM MQSeries ActiveX Write Message Error

Tags: vb6, activex, ibm-mq

I've a VB6 application with MQSeries Automation Classes for ActiveX. The problem is when i'm writing the message con the queue. I use this code :

This is how I open the connection and the relative queue :

```
Set MQSess = New MQSession
//Access Queue
Set QMgr = MQSess.AccessQueueManager(QueueManagerName)

Dim Queue As MQQueue
Dim msg As MQMessage
Dim pmo As MQPutMessageOptions

Dim ArrCar() As Byte

Set pmo = New MQPutMessageOptions

Set Queue = QMgr.AccessQueue(QueueName, OpenOption , RemoteQueueManagerName)
//OpenOption is a integer with value of 16 (MQOO_OUTPUT) 

strMsgAppo = Translate("*MESSAGE_TO_INSERT*", ASCII_To_EBCDIC_Table())

ReDim ArrCar(Len(strMsgAppo) - 1)
For lngI = 1 To Len(strMsgAppo)
    ArrCar(lngI - 1) = Asc(Mid(strMsgAppo, lngI, 1))
Next lngI

Call msg.Write(ArrCar) //Write the ByteArray

Call Queue.Put(msg, pmo)
```

The ASCII_To_EBCDIC_Table is a function used to change the encoding.

The error i'm getting from MQ is :

**MQAX200.MQMessage::Write CompletionCode = 2, ReasonCode = 2043, ReasonName = MQRC_OBJECT_TYPE_ERROR**

---

Is Anyone using this activex and can help me on how to write message in a queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The failure is on your msg.Write, and you should probably be using the .WrirteString method instead, after setting the .CharacterSet property to 37 (EBCDIC).

The hackish approach of your Translate() function might work, but only if assigned to a Byte array.  As you have things you're likely to see scrambling when the data is converted back to Unicode.  Or if Translate() does return a Byte array you'll have a mess with 8-bit data in a Unicode String (which can be fine but not with this MQ library).

You can probably just throw Translate() and your table away.

The IBM manual on this API is called "[Using the Component Object Model Interfac](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.amqtan.doc/wc10120_.htm)e." Check it out!

Comment: According to the docs, Message::Write does not throw a 2043.  If you are saying that the docs are wrong, let me know so I can submit a change on them.  Best I can tell, there's an implicit OPEN going wrong or else this is happening on the subsequent PUT. I'd love it is OP updated with the rest of the code or a trace.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on characterset, now i'm going to made this change and send to production group the executable, so they send me back a log to see what happened. Two question i've for you : 
1) Is the conversion to ebcdic necessary?
2) I've seen that i'm opening the queue with OUTPUT option only, maybe can be this that throw the error 2043?

Sorry for the minimum information but this program it's not made by me, i've only to solve this error... and this is the first time i use MQ...

Comment: @T.Rob Thanks for adding the link.  I left it out because IBM moves things around a lot and of course there are different versions of WebSphere MQ documentation.  But a link is better than no link.

Comment: Also, the error is MQAX200.MQMessage::Write ... which seems to be stating very clearly that .Write() is throwing the exception.  I'm not saying the docs are wrong, just a bit complex and confused to work with.  Sadly I can't be more specific, I haven't worked with MQ+VB6 for about 5 years myself.

Comment: @2GDev The EBCDIC conversion is needed if the application reading these messages expects it.  Otherwise you'll be storing Unicode (not ASCII at all).  My suspicion is that OBJECT_TYPE_ERROR is saying that .Write() is examining the Variant argument passed to it and saying "Hey, hey!  I am expecting a Byte array subtype and not a String subtype Variant expression."

Comment: ArrCar is a ByteArray... and otherwise the write accept a variant reference to a byte array (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.amqtan.doc/wc10120_.htm)

Comment: Ouch, I see that now that you point it out.  Sorry.  String-to-ByteArray assignment can be done directly without a loop too, but we don't know what your Translate() really returns.  It seems to be playing fast and loose with character encoding and conversions.  BTW: The Asc() function doesn't always return values from 0-255 either but I don't think that's your problem here.  At this point I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 2):

In the code snippet provided, I'm not seeing where the connection to the QMgr is made nor where the queue is opened.  Both of these steps must be completed before it is possible to put messages on the queue.

The 2043 reason code occurs when there is an invalid option in the Message Options field for a `PUT` or an `OPEN`. In this case the problem could either be on the PUT or an implicit `OPEN`, depending on what's in the code that was not provided and whether it contains an `OPEN`.

My suggestion would be to refer to the .Net samples provided in the installation and reconcile between those and your application.  The samples reside at `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\tools\dotnet\samples` in a default V7 installation.

Comment: Thanks but i don't have this installation.. otherwise i've the MQSeries Automation Classes for ActiveX and there is some example in vb.

Comment: A non-standard installation is the #1 cause of problems with WMQ client. Odd since the full client install is both free and supported.  If you want the samples, all the diagnostics and a full library set, it is available at http://bit.ly/SupportPacMQC7 for free download. In any case, 2043 is only documented to occur on a `CONNECT` or a `PUT` so either the docs are wrong, your write call is doing an implicit `CONNECT` or `PUT`, or there's some code you've left out that would help with diagnosis. Specifically, the options set in `MQCNO` for `CONNECT` or those in `MQPMO` for `PUT` are invalid.

Comment: So it was an install problem after all and you didn't get a vote or accept? +1 for effort, dude.

Comment: Actually, the accepted answer is the one by Bob suggesting improper use of the Message::Write API.  My name is on it because I edited it to add a link to the the docs Bob referenced.  Sooo...if code compiled on one machine works and another does not, what was the difference? Installed version?  Configuration?  Let us know so others with similar issues can benefit from this question.  Thx.

Comment: i'm waiting the production log and a little more information to explain me what happened. When i got this info i let you know, hope this help more people... And the accepted question is the one that give me a pratical solution.